# How to create "The Avery 5160 template"

Tags: java, jquery, templates, struts

I am working in web using strut framework. I am creating a print features. so user will be able to take a printout. But before printout, user also needs to enter **# labels**. So I am following to **The Avery 5160 template** and the sheet fits an 8.5" x 11" printer.  But i do not have any idea how to create such type templates?

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0020X9SZS?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=od_aui_detailpages00](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0020X9SZS)

Comment: Make a PDF with the measurements of the labels?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes. So user can take a printout of this pdf_preview that fits on 8.5" x 11" printer.These are sheets of labels that are 1" x 2 5/8"

Comment: ... I'm saying make a PDF that size. If you have no idea how to make a PDF then the question is too broad.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank you for suggestion. I will try and get back to you . Thanks